# Apache server-status is stuck in redirect loop

Tags: apache-2.4, azure, ubuntu-16.04, azure-networking

I am using Linux in Azure ( Ubuntu 16.04.06 LTS ) and I am trying to enable Apache status. However, after I enable the status module, when I go to http://localhost/server-status I get an error

> $ **wget http://localhost/server-status/**
>
> --2020-02-27 20:58:26--  http://localhost/server-status/ Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1 Connecting to localhost
>   (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting
>   response... 500 Internal Server Error 2020-02-27 20:58:26 ERROR 500:
>   Internal Server Error.

When I look at the apache **error.log** I get a message about too many internal redirects

> [Thu Feb 27 20:58:26.451285 2020] [core:error] [pid 86787] [client
>   127.0.0.1:51734] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use
>   'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use
>   'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

I used the standard command : **sudo a2enmod status** to enable the service and then rebooted apache. I am also using the default config file:

---- status.conf ---

```
<IfModule mod_status.c>
        # Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,
        # with the URL of http://servername/server-status
        <Location /server-status>
                SetHandler server-status
                #Require ip 192.0.2.0/24
                Require local
        </Location>
        # Keep track of extended status information for each request
        ExtendedStatus On
        <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
                # Show Proxy LoadBalancer status in mod_status
                ProxyStatus On
        </IfModule>  
</IfModule>
```

---- status.conf ---

I do have a redirect in place for all http traffic, but there is an exception for local host traffic.

--- default.conf ---

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$

        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

--- default.conf ---

I know the above config is not redirecting to https, I have tested this without the exception and I get a completely different message telling me the secure certificate doesn't match.

There is an .htaccess file in the default directory, but it looks pretty clean

--- .htaccess ---

```
RewriteEngine on \n
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/favicon.ico$
Options -Indexes
<Files deploy>
   Order allow,deny
   deny from all
</Files>
```

--- .htaccess ---

Does anyone have any experience with this functionality in Azure? Is this still something in configuration that I am missing?  Or does this simply not work in Azure due to some other configuration issue?  like could this be an Azure networking issue?

I appreciate any help.

Cheers,
    - GaryC - UnKulMunki -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the answer.**

The default host exists in **/var/www/html**﻿ ... 
In that directory is the webapp code, and it's .htaccess file...

However in the parent directory ( **/var/www/** ) is **ANOTHER** **.htaccess** file that was overloading the instructions from the subdirectory **.htaccess** file....

I added an exception for localhost and server-status works now!

Thanks...
Gary C